# TryParse in c++ .NET

Tags: visual-c++, ip, tryparse

How can I apply this syntax to validate IP address in vc++? I just want to check if the user input is valid ip address. There is no example in MSDN.

```
 public:
    static bool TryParse(
    String^ ipString, 
   [OutAttribute] IPAddress^% address
   )
```

Comment: can someone please provide an example? Thanks

Comment: I used Regex to validate IP address now and its OK...